# Memurai RediSearch `FT.CREATE` unknown command

Tags: node-redis, memurai

Using Memurai 3.1.4:

```
>memurai-cli --version
memurai-cli 3.1.4
```

which is the latest version as of now, and uses Redis 6.2. Using Memurai because I'm on Windows.

HOPING that Memurai comes out with Redis Modules, I tried running the command `FT.CREATE` and I got an error:

```
ERR unknown command `FT.CREATE`, with args beginning with: [MY INFO STUFF]
```

When I googled the error message I got [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1284) github issue from "StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis".

The comments on the issue mention Docker, but doesn't direct to any link that's for Windows.

When I prompt:

```
>memurai-cli info modules
# Modules

>
```

This is what I get. It's empty.

So ... I'm wondering there is no way to use any Redis modules, and if there is a way, please tell me. I need to use RediSearch.

Basically, I want to know how to use RediSearch command `FT.CREATE`, `FT.SEARCH` and all that using the fresh and latest Memurai (only available for Windows).

Comment: Hi! Can you provide more context?
What version of Memurai are you using?
How did you load the module?
Did you recompile the module for Windows?

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask may also be helpful.

Comment: @Zak I'm using the latest version of Memurai which happens to be 3.1.4. So, I just want to know how to use RediSearch features like `FT.CREATE`, `FT.SEARCH` and all that on Memurai because when I tried using it, it gave me error. And when I tried to install or load RediSearch module from Redis download center, RediSearch1 and 2 are not available for Windows. Does your latest Memurai run these commands?

Comment: Memurai hasn't distributed RediSearch in the past because of the module's licensing. However, it's probable that people have compiled RediSearch for Windown their own.

However, with the recent licensing changes for Redis modules, we might be able to share Windows DLLs of RediSearch. I'll look into it. Keep in mind though that the binary would be SSPL licensed, meaning (roughly) that if you used it as part of a SaaS, you'd need to freely license the entire source code of your service.

Comment: Sadly, compiling RediSearch for Windows will require some rewrites of the code. I'll look into it with the team, but it can't be high priority at the moment. For now, you'll be better off using Docker, as suggested by @simon-prickett, or using WSL, as documented by Redis at https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-windows/

Answer (score 3):

To use RediSearch you will need a Redis Stack instance of Redis.  That's available using Docker:

```
docker run -d --name redis-stack -p 6379:6379 -p 8001:8001 redis/redis-stack:latest
```

Instructions can be found here at redis.io:

https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/docker/

Redis Stack consists of Redis plus additional capabilities implemented as Redis modules, all bundled together.  These capabilities include the search functionality that you are looking for `FT.<whatever>` commands.  You also get the RedisInsight GUI to examine the data in Redis.  To access that, point a browser at http:/localhost:8001 when running the Docker container.